# How to make Ubuntu a CLI after installing from live usb?

Tags: 11.10, boot, command-line, grub2

I am trying to install Ubuntu as a command line only but only found that you cant really do it off a USB as the alt. CD requires it be on a CD to install and I looked around but couldn't find how to make Ubuntu CLI after installing so there any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative or server install is really the better way to accomplish this. But since I've got some spare time to bash up some problems. Here is a solution to your question. (Did this on ubuntu 11.10)

1) Start off by disabling `gdm`/`lightdm` by running

`echo "manual" | sudo tee -a /etc/init/{gdm,lightdm}.override`

2) Edit out the `vt.handoff=7` part in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` This is can be done using

`sudo sed -i~ s/vt\.handoff=7// /etc/grub.d/10_linux` (This also leaves a backup called `10_linux~` just in case).

3) Remove `quiet` and `splash` options from `GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` by running

`sudo  sed -i~ s/quiet\ splash// /etc/default/grub` (backed up as `grub~`)

4) Update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`by running

`sudo update-grub`

5) Reboot and rejoice.

Now it's just a matter of removing unwanted/unused packages.

Comment: Will I still be able to get to the GUI if I need to

Comment: Yes, just run `startx`.

Comment: Will it go in to unitey (Spelled wrong) or another GUI? sorry for the other questions I'm at not at home

Comment: It will most likely go to your default window manager.

Comment: Oh ok and also number 2 is not working for me it's saying ~ is not a valid option

Comment: Nevermind you forgot sed i think

Comment: yup... saw that now. will update the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I just tryed this in 12.04 and it works except when I startx all I have is my background and everything that's in my desktop folder the side bar and menu at the too is not there any help fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to install ubuntu server instead , i know ubuntu server from what i've seen still has all the trimmings but is cli only

but there is a way if you dont mind messing around for a bit and i found it [here](http://nixcraft.com/linux-software/2654-ubuntu-set-default-runlevel-etc-inittab.html)

or try `init 3` as root when logging in